# Smoothly scroll to specified position in Android gallery

Tags: android

Is there a sane way to programatically scroll to show a specific component in a Gallery - the equivalent of setSelection(int) but with smooth scrolling rather than a direct jump?

Comment: there is an overload of setSelection() that takes a boolean for animation. maybe it does what you want? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection%28int,%20boolean%29

Comment: if i read code right it just gets ignored... you could try to make your own method using smoothScrollTo().

Comment: Yup, the setSelection(int, boolean) doesn't do the trick. The problem with smoothScrollTo() is twofold: firstly working out the location that you need to scroll to for a given index, and secondly the fact that it's not available in Gallery - it's defined in the scroll view classes, which Gallery doesn't extend. My current plan would be to use a Scroller in a similar way to smoothScrollTo(), but the problem is still working out where exactly we have to scroll to.

Comment: Further, scrollTo and scrollBy don't work for the Gallery (they don't hook into the private API for updating which components are displayed in the view). Gallery's a nice component if it already does what you want it to do, but an absolute pig if you want to extend its functionality, apparently...

Comment: The same here... I'm trying to understand how gallery works and extending it without copying most of the code is almost impossible... All the members are private and the public methods don't help much...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've found an easy way to do it ! It consists of calling the onFling() method directly...

```
MotionEvent e1 = MotionEvent.obtain(
    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), 
    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),  
    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 89.333336f, 265.33334f, 0);
MotionEvent e2 = MotionEvent.obtain(
    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), 
    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), 
    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 300.0f, 238.00003f, 0);

gallery.onFling(e1, e2, -800, 0);
```

There should be a better way to do it. onFling() should be called when the Gallery gets flinged, not to fling it.

Comment: I understand that this is deprecated going forward, but did you end up finding a nice solution that you could share as to how you paired the fling with the item that you are selecting?  Manipulating the fling is does produce an effect that would be nice to replicate but it seems to be dependent on several factors.